# ¿Cómo hacer un COUNT interno a una consulta con una condición ? 2

Tags: sql

Quiero hacer un count solamente cuando swipe.state = 2,3,5,6,8 o 9. Los demás se dejaran en cero. Por el momento tengo esta primera parte, ¿ como hacer ambas ?

```
   SELECT  COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.eclipse_id, swipe.subscriber_id FROM swipe
      WHERE swipe.state= 2 OR swipe.state = 3 or swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state =6 or swipe.state=8 or swipe.state=9
        GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id,swipe.eclipse_id
          ORDER BY (swipe.subscriber_id) ASC
```

Comment: que es lo demas?? eso anda bien (bah no lo probe, se ve bien).

Comment: Ayudaría que incluyeras un ejemplo de la tabla que quieres consultar y el resultado que esperas.

Answer (score 2):

Si entendí lo que dices, no se puede con un `count` pero se puede hacer algo parecido con `sum`, por ejemplo así:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN swipe.state IN (2,3,4,5,6,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        swipe.eclipse_id, 
        swipe.subscriber_id 
        FROM swipe
        GROUP BY 
          swipe.subscriber_id, 
          swipe.eclipse_id, 
          CASE WHEN swipe.state IN (2,3,4,5,6,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ORDER BY (swipe.subscriber_id) ASC
```

Comment: 2 pequeños comentarios. Primero, esto sí se puede hacer con un `COUNT` (`COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 END)`. En segundo lugar, no es necesario usar `CASE WHEN swipe.state IN (2,3,4,5,6,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` en el `GROUP BY`. Aparte de eso, creo que esto es lo que quiere el usuario

Comment: Muchas gracias, es casi lo que busco : hay `eclipse_id` con `subscriber_id` que no estan en todas las casas de los otros suscriber.

Comment: Mira vos... En alguna versión vieja de SQLServer el COUNT de esta manera no funcionaba así que uso siempre el SUM, buen dato. Lo del Group by es suponiendo que se quiere tener dos grupos, el que cumple con una condición y el que no.